# Read and Write an Array of Structs to binary file. C++

Tags: c++, fstream

This is a header file part of a bigger project, but I am trying to save an array of structs to a binary file. When I do this (with my current code) it reads back very random information and not sure if I am close to getting it right on saving the information.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Reserv{
private:
    struct ReservStruct{
        int seatNum = 0;
        int custID = 0;
        int resvID = 0;
        int resvIDcount;
    };
    int resvIDcount;
    static int const numberOfSeats = 10;
    ReservStruct Seat[numberOfSeats];

public:

    /* Read and Write Files ***********************************/
    void writeResvIDcount(){
        ofstream IDfile("resvidcount.txt", ios::binary);
        IDfile.write((char*)&resvIDcount,sizeof(resvIDcount));
        IDfile.close();
    }
    void readResvIDcount(){
        ifstream IDfile("resvidcount.txt", ios::binary);
        IDfile.read((char*)&resvIDcount,sizeof(resvIDcount));
        IDfile.close();
    }
    void writeReservations(){
        ofstream resfile("reservations.txt", ios::binary);
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfSeats; i++) {
            resfile.write((char*)&Seat[i], sizeof(Seat));
        }
    }
    void readReservations(){
        ifstream resfile("reservations.txt", ios::binary);
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfSeats; i++) {
            resfile.read((char*)&Seat[i], sizeof(Seat));
        }
    }
    /*********************************************************/


    void ReserveSeat(int seatNumber, int customerID){
        if (Seat[seatNumber].resvID == 0) {
            Seat[seatNumber].seatNum = seatNumber;
            Seat[seatNumber].custID = customerID;
            Seat[seatNumber].resvID = resvIDcount;
            cout << "Reservation ID: " << resvIDcount << endl;
            resvIDcount = resvIDcount+1;
            writeResvIDcount();
            writeReservations();
        }
        if (Seat[seatNumber].resvID != 0) {
            addToWaitingList(seatNumber, customerID);
        }
    }
    void CancelReservation(int seatNumber){
        Seat[seatNumber].seatNum = seatNumber;
        Seat[seatNumber].custID = 0;
        Seat[seatNumber].resvID = 0;
        cout << "Reservation on seat number " << Seat[seatNumber].seatNum << " has been cancelled." << endl;

    }


    Reserv(){
        readResvIDcount();
        readReservations();
        int reservchoice;
        cout << "1: New Reservation\n2: Cancel Reservation\n";
        cin >> reservchoice;
        if (reservchoice ==1) {
            int customerID;
            int seatToReserve;
            cout << "Enter Customer ID:";
            cin >> customerID;
            cout << "Seat Number:";
            cin >> seatToReserve;
            ReserveSeat(seatToReserve, customerID);
        }
        if (reservchoice==2) {
            int seatNum;
            cout << "Seat Number:";
            cin >>seatNum;
            CancelReservation(seatNum);

        }


    }


};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Writing to a binary file can be tricky. More often than not you cannot simply write the structure to a file. A `std::string` is the classic example. A `std::string` often does not contain the data that it represents. It contains a pointer to the data, and if you write the `string` object to the file, you write the pointer. That pointer will almost certainly be meaningless or outright dangerous when you read the file back again. It is best to establish a data protocol and "serialize" the data.

Comment: Class String has a dynamic size so you cannot directly write objects of such type to a file and read them back; You can write but a `string sLine` is initialized with size 0 so how can it know the size of data in the file to allocate memory for? Thus the workaround this is consider `Serialization/De-Serialization`.

Comment: You never initialize `resvIDcount`. It initially contains random garbage, which you then dutifully write to the file and read back.

Comment: After writing `resvIDCount`, you close the file. Then you open again for writing without `std::ios_base::append` flag and write the `Seat`s. In reading, you do the same thing. This is in addition to not initializing `resvIDCount` variable.